# Symfony 2 app.php vs app_dev.php

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using the Symfony 2 php framework, which has a couple of different usage environments: development, production and test. The app.php front controller accesses the production environment and the app_dev.php front controller accesses the development environment. Can anyone familiar with Symfony advise what is the best way to restrict the development environment to developers? I don't want the development version of my web application to be viewable by users of my site, they should be restricted to using the production environment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, out of the box, the standard distribution has an IP-based guard check at the [top of the dev controller](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/app_dev.php).

```
// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
        '127.0.0.1',
        '::1',
    ))
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

However, as the comments indicate, you aren't beholden to that approach. For example, if you're running Apache, you can [add basic HTTP Authentication](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) to the dev and test controllers.

Comment: One should also mention that simply not uploading the app_dev.php file to your production server is also an option.

Comment: Capifony, for examples, removes all the app_*.php files upon deployment in order to prevent leaking strange environments to the production servers.

Comment: Any black hat hacker can generate all of the $_SERVER settings required to bypass the check in that controller. While it will filter most lazy attackers, you'd want a minimum of basic http authentication if you need to run the dev console from the server. The **best** idea is to assume that it doesn't belong on the server and stick to that practice for normal deployment.